# Interpretation of Mantel r correlations

Tags: p-value, interpretation, spatial, distance, partial-correlation

I am using `mantel()` in [R package ecodist](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ecodist/versions/2.0.5/topics/mantel) to perform a series of partial Mantel tests.

I am examining the correlation between a species composition (Bray-Curtis dissimilarity) matrix and a series of environmental and spatial (UTM) variables (as separate Euclidean distance matrices).

The structure of the mantel equation is:

```
mantel(spp.dist ~ x.dist + a.dist + b.dist + .... + geo.dist, nperm=10000, nboot=500)
```

where `spp.dist` = the species dissimilarity matrix; `x.dist` is an environmental variable of interest; `a.dist` & `b.dist` and `...` are all other environmental variables; and `geo.dist` = dissimilarity matrix of UTMN & UTME. `x.dist` cycles between all other env variables to determine its contribution to the pattern of correlation. `nperm` and `nboot` set number of permutations and iterations for bootstrapping to use, respectively.

Here is an example of output (modified slightly from actual data):

```
            plot        Year          position      pH
mantelr     0.03960184  0.000806223   -0.02970148   -0.009351586
pval1       0.0001      0.4534         0.9977        0.6981
pval2       1           0.5467         0.0024        0.302
pval3       0.0001      0.9407         0.0144        0.5925
llim.2.5%   0.03393448 -0.007369118   -0.03699412   -0.019564176
ulim.97.5%  0.04652775  0.008779442   -0.02203297    0.001134167
```

The R-help link included states:

> ```
> mantelr = Mantel coefficient.
> pval1 = one-tailed p-value (null hypothesis: r <= 0).
> pval2 = one-tailed p-value (null hypothesis: r >= 0).
> pval3 = two-tailed p-value (null hypothesis: r = 0).
> llim  = lower confidence limit.
> ulim  =  upper confidence limit.
> ```

So I understand that the mantel r is essentially the correlation between the `spp.dist` matrix and each variable after having controlled for all other variables. **But 2 questions I'm unsure about:**

**1. How do I interpret negative mantel r values?**

**2. Do I pay more attention to the one or two tail p-value? Which should I report?**

Answer (score 1):

**1. How to interpret negative Mantel r values:**

Mantel r values can fall within a range between -1 to 1.  An r value of -1 suggests a strong negative correlation, 0 suggests no relationship at all and 1 suggests a strong positive relationship.

If, for example, we were interested in the relationship between wet/dry locations and presence of plants: an r of 1 would suggest that plants grow in wet locations (i.e. as water levels increase then plant abundance also increases).  An r of -1 suggests that plants grow in dry locations (i.e. as water levels increase then plant abundance decreases).  Finally, an r of 0 would suggest that there is no spatial relationship between water and plant presence.

**2. Interpreting and reporting one or two tail p-values:**
It depends on your null hypothesis.  In the R package ecodist you can choose between three null hypotheses.

The null hypothesis for "pval1" is that the Mantel r statistic will be equal to or smaller than zero (i.e. that there is a negative spatial correlation between variables).

Conversely, the null hypothesis for "pval2" is that the Mantel r statistic is equal to or greater than zero (i.e. that there is a positive spatial correlation between variables).

The null hypothesis for "pval3" is that the Mantel r statistic is equal to 0 (i.e. that there is no spatial correlation between variables).  In other words, if one is interested in rejecting the null hypothesis that there is no spatial relationship between variables (either a positive *or* negative relationship) then pval3 is the reasonable choice.